# Force camera.lookAt to maintain current Z rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

So, I'm putting together a 3D project that will eventually make it's way onto a kiosk in the office of a client, basically shows all of their branches as points on a globe. One of the features requested is that end users be able to swipe on the screen to orbit around the globe, in addition, they should be able to rotate the camera on it's Z axis via a rotation gesture. The problem is I'm using camera.lookAt in the animation loop, which relies on the up vector being updated correctly whenever I rotate the camera in order to not "snap" back to place along the previous up vector when a user swipes, and for the life of me, I cannot get it to cooperate.

Currently, what I'm doing to update the up vector (based off of another stackoverflow thread with a similar issue) is this:

```
//Current full 360 degree angle of rotation, calculated earlier
let radian = THREE.Math.degToRad(full);

//Create new vector at radian angle to camera's current position
let v1 = new THREE.Vector3(_this.object.position.x + Math.cos(radian), _this.object.position.y + Math.sin(radian), _this.object.position.z).sub( _this.object.position ).normalize();

//_this.target = 0,0,0
let v2 = _this.target.clone().sub( _this.object.position ).normalize();

//Cross vectors to get the proper up
let v3 = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors( v1, v2 ).normalize();

_this.object.up.copy( v3 );
```

And this works... up to the point where the camera seemingly inverts once I head near the side of the globe opposite the camera's starting position (0,0,1.75) and then negates my rotations (as far as I can tell) which causes the same "snap" to a different rotation like before.

Once I rotate the camera, I want it to maintain the rotation when using lookAt, regardless of the lookAt inverting everything.